# Wildcards in requestmapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, http-status-code-404

I am working on my Spring application and as per below code, I am mapping multiple URL's to one method. I am making one method "root" to serve all the request which starts with index and root.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "index*"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String root(Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome to index page.");  
    model.addAttribute("hello", "Welcome to index page." );     
    return "index";
}
```

The above `"index*"` is working fine in case of `"index", "index123", "index.html" and "index.txt"` and request is directed to the mapped method i.e. `"root"` but its not working for `"index.jsp"`. In case of `"index.jsp"` i am getting `"HTTP Status 404" "The requested resource is not available"`.

Excerpt from `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Can someone let me know the reason behind this and how can I make it work?

Comment: I dont want to map all the jsps, just want to have one single method for index* type request.

Comment: In your web.xml is dispatcher servlet mapped with "/" url?

Comment: yes, added Excerpt from `web.xml` in my question above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be happening because the servlet container maps *.jsp requests to the `JspServlet` in order to compile and execute the jsp. If you're using Tomcat this happens in the top level `web.xml` in Tomcat's `conf` directory. This would mean that requests ending in *.jsp would be intercepted before they reached your controller. The `JspServlet` would attempt to load the `index.jsp` file based on the path in the webapp and would return a 404 when it couldn't find it.

For `/index.jsp`, you may do best to actually create this file in the root of the webapp so that you don't see a 404. You could add some code to it to redirect requests somewhere else (perhaps to `/index.html` - or to some other entry point of your application).